# Compute fundamental matrix with 8 point algorithm

Tags: image-processing, geometry

I need to write an own implementation of computing the fundamental matrix between two images based on the corresponding image coordinates without using OpenCV.

Is it possible to describe this algorithm in its simplest form in accordance with the following function? a simple and straightforward formula.

FMatrixEightPoint()

```
Input Arguments:
```

points1(x,y)−pixel coordinates in the first image ,
   corresponding to points2 in the second image
  points2(x,y)−pixel coordinates in the second image ,
   corresponding to points1 in the first image

```
 Output :
```

F − the fundamental matrix between the first image and the second image

Comment: Did you take a look at the [algorithm itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-point_algorithm)? There is no "simple formula", this is the algorithm: Build the constraint matrix, then extract the vector corresponding to the smallest singular value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to describe the algorithm in the mentioned form.

If you would use OpenCV, you could just use [findFundamentalMat](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Mat%20findFundamentalMat(InputArray%20points1,%20InputArray%20points2,%20int%20method,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20OutputArray%20mask)). This also provides the 8-point method for computing the fundamental matrix.

The example (in C++) taken from the OpenCV documentation, but adapted (using the RANSAC algorithm for computing the fundamental matrix):

```
// Example. Estimation of fundamental matrix using the 8-point algorithm
int point_count = 8; // must be >= 8
vector<Point2f> points1(point_count);
vector<Point2f> points2(point_count);

// initialize the points here ... */
for( int i = 0; i < point_count; i++ )
{
    points1[i] = ...;
    points2[i] = ...;
}

Mat fundamental_matrix =
 findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, CV_FM_8POINT);
```

If you want to write your own function, it would look like this (no valid code)

```
Matrix findFundamentalMat(Array points1, Array points2)
{
    Matrix fundamentalMatrix;
    // compute fundamental matrix based on input points1 and points2 or call OpenCV's findFundamentalMat
    return fundamentalMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to write my own code in c ++, but I don't understand the steps of the algorithm. Can you help me?

Comment: @HakanMuratAksüt You should edit your question and add thw code you have written so far. Furthermore you should write explicit questions about which part of the algorithm you do not understand. There are also many implementation examples, e.g. in Matlab available if you search for it